# Can a title attribute be added to links generated by asp.net sitemap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using the MCV Site Map provider and it is working well, but I would like to add a `title` attribute to the `a href` tags generated by the sitemap. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Does `description` attribute of `mvcSiteMapNode` become the `title` of the link?

Comment: I tried that and it did not produce any extra client side code. I think it is just used for coding notes.

Comment: I see. Well if there're no built-in server-side or declarative methods, you can always do this in client-site JavaScript

Comment: Also, not sure about MVC Map Provider, but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.description.aspx `Description` acts as both documentation and tooltip for the node in standard ASP.NET map, technically this should be the case in MVC one

Comment: Maybe it is broken then, I will open a bug report with the MVC guys and see what they say, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The makers of the MVC SiteMapProvider have confirmed this is a bug in version 3. They have given the following code change which has worked.

SiteMapNodeModel.cshtml:

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@if (Model.IsCurrentNode && Model.SourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString() != "MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper")  { 
    <text>@Model.Title</text>
} else if (Model.IsClickable) { 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Description))
    {
        <a href="@Model.Url">@Model.Title</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a href="@Model.Url" title="@Model.Description">@Model.Title</a>
    }
} else { 
    <text>@Model.Title</text>
}
```